# RSSOwl error when launching the application ("might have disabled stack guard")

Tags: java, debugging, gtk, debian, rss-reader

I've downloaded RSSOwl and tried to run its executable file but it gives an error in the console:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/narayan/Downloads/rssowl/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
>   It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
>   Thu Feb 12 23:26:54 WET 2015 - [main] Bundle tracker is not set
>   (RSSOwl:9928): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
>   (RSSOwl:9928): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

The 2 last lines are not severe. The problem is the previous lines.
I'm using Debian Jessie 64bit, installed Eclipse to try to solve it but no good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running java 5/6 with JNI on java 7 gives stack guard warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889113/running-java-5-6-with-jni-on-java-7-gives-stack-guard-warning)